# Does the method can solve the string result problem?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the problem below.

When I want to get the result with "querystring" from other cell,it just return the string type result.

When I get the "querystring" from B10,it just show the

```
=filter(B2:B5,B2:B5 = "John")
```

It's not incorrect,but I want the result "John".

How can I solve it to get the result directly or it need to put double quotation,single quotation at somewhere?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Can you give us a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @MikeTung  Thank you.I edit the question again,
I'm not sure whether it may help make question more clearer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add **`=`** in front of the formula

[image]

---

it kind of does not make sense what you ask, however, try to press:

[image]

which will trigger formula mode view to on/off

Comment: I don't understand,why does'nt make sense?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hf2GURc8eYEOzImX4qIySH0IpDGe_7TedU6de4Xxa4o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you,but I know about that.
I want to know the thing is the string result only can get the string type result,the array result can get the array result yesterday.

Comment: You let me know about this,thank you very much.
In other people's side,it may be a rediculous question.